# How do I group by using an average?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I need to display the names of a business that has an average quantity of less than or equal to 300.

**Table S:**

```
BusNAME     BusNUM 
-------   ---------
  Bob        A1    
  Lee        A2      
  Ashley     A3
```

**Table SP:**

```
BusNUM     QTY 
-------   ---------
A1         300    
A1         400     
A1         100 
A2         100
A2         100
A2         200
A3         400
A3         300
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
SELECT s.BusName
FROM S s
JOIN SP p ON p.BusNum = s.BusNum
GROUP By s.BusName
HAVING AVG(p.QTY) <= 300;
```

Comment: You just miss ON: `JOIN SP p ON p.BusNum = s.BusNum`

Comment: Remove the quotes around 300. It's numeric value, not a string value.

Comment: Hey all thank you for your assistance. I am now getting an error. "S". "SNUM" : invalid identifier.

Comment: what is this `SNUM` column? . Edit your question with details .

Comment: Hello Kaushik, my apologies. I was trying to apply it to my actual assignment. I made dummy data. With the dummy data, I'm getting an error with "P" and "BusNum".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the `BusNUM` and the Average of the `Qty` from table `SP` into a temporary table, then do a normal join! You can do:

```
SELECT S.BusName
FROM S, (SELECT BusNUM, AVG(QTY) AS Average
         FROM SP
         GROUP BY BusNUM) Temporal
WHERE S.BusNUM = Temporal.BusNUM
AND Temporal.Average <= 300;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm getting an Error at Line 4: SQL command not properly ended. Do I need a comma there?

Comment: @Lizzie Try dropping the `AS` before the table name `Temporal`. Tried it like that and worked for me. Let me know.